# What is a homotopy between bisimplicial maps

Tags: homotopy-theory, simplicial-stuff

I originally posted it on [stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/651901/what-is-a-homotopy-between-bisimplicial-maps), but did not get any comments or answer, so I try my luck here.

I am looking for the naive notion of homotopy.

For maps $f, g: A\to B$ of simplicial sets $\Delta^{op}\to Sets$, a homotopy $H$ is a simplicial map $H:A\times\Delta^{1}\to B$ such that $H|_{A\times\{0\}}=f$ and $H|_{A\times\{1\}}=g$, or equivalently a collection of maps $H_i: X_n\to Y_{n+1}, 0\le i\le n$ subject to a bunch of identities, see [encyclopedia of math](http://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Simplicial_object_in_a_category).

Now for maps $f, g:A\to B$ of bisimplicial sets $\Delta^{op}\times\Delta^{op}\to Sets$, what is a homotopy between them?

Is it a map $A\times\Delta^{1,1}\to B$ such that a suitable boudary condition hold? But now there are four vertexes of $\Delta^{1,1}$.

Obviously, we may define a map $A\times\Delta^{0,1}\to B$ or $A\times\Delta^{1,0}\to B$ to be vertical/horizontal homotopy.

Comment: I guess there are many possible answers. From a more general point this question is answered by giving a model structure on the category of bisimplicial sets. Then you could decipher the explicit notion of homotopy. A quick search gave me http://www.math.uwo.ca/~jardine/papers/HomTh/lecture008.pdf It contains a list with some model structures..

Comment: I think, depending on the context, one just defines it to be a vertical or horizontal homotopy. There is no reason, why there should be a single definition (unless you view in the context of model categories where you have an exact notion of a cylinder object, which leaves you a lot of freedom to choose it).

Answer (score 1):

Following Stephan's comment, we can define model structures on s<sup>2</sup>Set, using which we can [define left and right homotopies](http://hopf.math.purdue.edu/Dwyer-Spalinski/theories.pdf). However, if we look at your maps A×Δ<sup>0,1</sup>→B and A×Δ<sup>1,0</sup>→B, drawing a simple picture allows us to think of A×Δ<sup>1,0</sup>→B as a horizonal homotopy and A×Δ<sup>0,1</sup>→B as vertical homotopy with a suitable orientation of the Cartesian space. A general homotopy can then naively be considered some sort of "composition" of the two - first vertical then horizontal homotopy, or first horizontal then vertical homotopy. But the best one to go with would be the one defined by a chosen model structure on s<sup>2</sup>Set.